# List to Set without affecting the order of the elements

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I have a List of Strings as `["abc", "xyz", "abc", "mno", "123"]`

now I want the unique values out of this list. To do that I am converting the List to HashSet.

I am able to achieve the same but the order of elements is affected. The output is very random, one of the result is `["123", "xyz", "abc", "mno"]`.

But I want resulted set containing the items in the same order as the arraylist. How can I achieve this?

```
List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>();
//add the parameter to List
Set<String> parameterSet=new HashSet<String>(parameters);
```

Comment: Use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `LinkedHashSet`

```
List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>();

                                            Call the List here
                                                     |
Set<String> parameterSet=new LinkedHashSet<String>(parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `LinkedHashSet`. Otherwise it won't work since a `HashSet` is not ordered.

Comment: Correct, I was thinking about `TreeSet` but op needs insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LinkedHashSet`.

From JavaDocs:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set
>   interface,  with predictable iteration order.  This implementation
>   differs from  HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked
>   list running through  all of its entries.  This linked list defines
>   the iteration ordering,  which is the order in which elements were
>   inserted into the set  (*insertion-order*).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) which is a set that maintains insertion order

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinkedHashSet`.
From [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the
>   order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).
>   Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted
>   into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is
>   invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the
>   invocation.)